# Storing Dates in MongoDB

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I have seen quite a few questions here about the best storage ideologies for dates in MongoDB. most of the answers boiling down to using JavaScript Date objects.

I have another question, however: which is the most performant way to store dates?

I am operating on a collection of about 5 million entries and performs about 500 ranged read operations per minute on it asking for records $gt or $lt the current timestamp. How are indices built around the native JavaScript Date object? Are they more performant that storing an integer timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates are stored as 64 bit integers in MongoDB.

See the BSON spec http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

Comment: The driver is responsible for converting the DateTime object to an int64 before it even goes to MonogDB.  MongoDB will never know about a DateTime object.  The actual queries will be on int64's.  The DateTime objects are just for your code. So yes, there is no difference on performance (though technically, since there is only one option, there is no contest)